# UI design for Arabic Support apps in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to provide Arabic Language support for my Android app. Arabic Language support is provided by default by Android 2.3. So, I want to know  if there are any UI changes that I need to do while providing support for Arabic language in Android.
As the letters in Arabic were written from right to left, what are the constraints that I need to follow in Android UI layout design and also in coding?
Or else otherwise will Android itself take care of reading the data we entered, whether it is  typed from right to left.

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue?

Comment: Am also facing same problem can anyone suggest...

Comment: i am having the same problem. i thing is possible to make right-to-left XML for arabic and left-to-right for english. file name and id for each controls should be same. is there any other way [easy] to do this things?

Comment: @HirenDabhi RTL support is easy to implement once you get the habit of using Start & End instead of Right and Left where needed. Read my comment for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have use this code and working perfect try it..

```
public static void change_setting_arabic(Context con) {
            try {
                Locale locale = new Locale("ar");

                Class amnClass = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");
                Object amn = null;
                Configuration config = null;

                // amn = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault();
                Method methodGetDefault = amnClass.getMethod("getDefault");
                methodGetDefault.setAccessible(true);
                amn = methodGetDefault.invoke(amnClass);

                // config = amn.getConfiguration();
                Method methodGetConfiguration = amnClass
                        .getMethod("getConfiguration");
                methodGetConfiguration.setAccessible(true);
                config = (Configuration) methodGetConfiguration.invoke(amn);

                // config.userSetLocale = true;
                Class configClass = config.getClass();
                Field f = configClass.getField("userSetLocale");
                f.setBoolean(config, true);

                // set the locale to the new value
                config.locale = locale;

                // amn.updateConfiguration(config);
                Method methodUpdateConfiguration = amnClass.getMethod(
                        "updateConfiguration", Configuration.class);
                methodUpdateConfiguration.setAccessible(true);
                methodUpdateConfiguration.invoke(amn, config);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.d("error lang change-->", "" + e.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little pro-tip from Roman Nurik (from the Android team):
Use gravities of START and END instead of LEFT and RIGHT for better RTL support. Although the constants are only defined in API 14 [0], they are backward compatible because 
(1) they're inlined at compile time and (2) they're functionally equivalent to LEFT and RIGHT on earlier devices because of their least-significant bytes:

START = 0x00800003
LEFT = 0x00000003
END = 0x00800005
RIGHT = 0x00000005

You can see the difference between START and LEFT with
`<TextView layout_width=match_parent, gravity=start, text=[hebrew characters here]>`
 the text layout will see your Hebrew characters and align text to the right boundary of the TextView instead of the left because of gravity=start. And note, the default horizontal gravity of TextView is start, not left.

So, left is always left and right is always right, but start and end can be either left or right, depending on the locale.